# What is causing a push to origin to hang up, with Github Desktop?

Tags: github, gitlab

I am trying to push some files to a remote GitLab repo using GitHub Desktop. And after getting it to finish writing the objects, by increasing the buffer size in the command line; I am stuck halfway in the push.

I have this pop up, while it is stuck,
`Total 505 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0`.

What could fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with our implementation of Gitlab. These suggestions did help to figure it out.

Comment: Could you add a bit more details? What was the issue and how you were able to fix it or not?

Comment: Git LFS does not work with gitlab if it is private; My team was able to work that out and switch to a new VC system.

Answer (score 10):

Searching for a similar problem, I found this solution [here](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/14331#issuecomment-1308575748):

1. anywhere run
   `git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400`
2. in your local repo run `git rm -r --cached .`

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the same issue persists when pushing from command-line

```
cd /path/to/repository
git remote -v
# make sure the URL is the right GitLab one
git push
```

That way, you will know if the problem is actually with GitHub Desktop, or something else.

Comment: When I did it from the command line, I got nothing under the git remote -v command or git remote.

Comment: @SkilledRook Assuming you are in the right folder (your local repository), type `git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/<you>/<yourRepo>` (replace `<you>` by your GitLab account name, and `<yourRepo>` by the name of the remote repository you are pushing to: it should be a brand new empty repository)